# Centering a menu where some items may disappear

Tags: html, css, menu, center

**What I am trying to do:**
I am trying to center some text (an areas name). this text will have 3 different configurations:

1. Text and a floating right arrow
2. Floating left arrow  text and floating right arrow
3. Floating left arrow and text

These arrows go to the next area or previous area, if there is no next or previous area the arrow disappears, but the text still shows the current areas name.

**Problem:**
This text simply wont stay centered when the arrows disappear or appear its center shifts over accordingly

I have tried many different ways of accomplishing this and all of which have failed, it seems to be a simple enough problem, but I can't figure it out.

**Here are some tests I tried in JSfiddle:**
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/5vTE5/

```
<ul style="text-align: center; list-style:none;">
    <li style="float:left; display:inline">
        Left float
    </li>
        <li style="display:inline;">
        Centered
    </li>
        <li style="float:right; display:inline">
        Right
    </li>
</ul>
<br/>

<div style="text-align: center;">
<span style="float: left;">Left text</span>
<span style="text-align: center;">Centered Text</span>
<span style="float: right;">Right Text</span>
</div>
<!--Right is gone-->
<div style="text-align: center;">
<span style="float: left;">Left text</span>
<span style="text-align: center;">Centered Text</span>
</div>

<!--left is gone-->

<div style="text-align: center;">
<span style="text-align: center;">Centered Text</span>
<span style="float: right;">Right Text</span>
</div>

<br/>
<!--This text is centered to the size of the window, or its parent-->
<div style="text-align: center;">Centered Text</div>
```

**Images:**
[image: Floating left arrow and text]
[image: Floating left arrow text and floating right arrow]
[image: Text and a floating right arrow]

The images are narrow so I have also uploaded them to imgur to make them a bit more visible:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpjqO.jpg

Currently I am doing it with as a list.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Could you please supply the fiddle? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep your structure in pages where the right, left elements are not displayed. Example http://jsfiddle.net/CtKgr/2/
CSS

```
li
{
    width:33%;
    border:1px solid red;
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline-block;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
}

.center
{
    text-align:center;   
}

.right
{
    text-align:right;   
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Left
    </li>
    <li class="center">
        Centered
    </li>
    <li class="right">
        Right
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li class="center">
        Centered
    </li>
    <li class="right">
        Right
    </li>
</ul>


<ul>
    <li>
        Left float
    </li>
    <li class="center">
        Centered
    </li>
    <li class="right">

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now that I think about it, I guess I could have used a table as well. *face hits desk*

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `float` correctly. This is a common misunderstanding and one of the hardest things I had to learn when learning `float` in conjunction with other CSS attributes.

`Float`, [as described by W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp), tells an inline element to go as far to the left or right as it possibly can. So you can float some items left and some items right, if you want, but what that means is that each item is going to try to go as far left or as far right as it can.

Beyond this, float actually does not play nicely with inline lists. Instead, follow [this SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304186/css-how-can-i-center-a-horizontal-list-displayinline-not-working) and remove float entirely. If you want each item to float left or right you should consider setting static widths for each inline list item and assigning `text-align: left`, `text-align: center`, and `text-align:right` where appropriate.